# Problem with shelve module?

Tags: python, shelve

Using the shelve module has given me some surprising behavior. keys(), iter(), and iteritems() don't return all the entries in the shelf! Here's the code:

```
cache = shelve.open('my.cache')
# ...
cache[url] = (datetime.datetime.today(), value)
```

later:

```
cache = shelve.open('my.cache')
urls = ['accounts_with_transactions.xml', 'targets.xml', 'profile.xml']
try:
    print list(cache.keys()) # doesn't return all the keys!
    print [url for url in urls if cache.has_key(url)]
    print list(cache.keys())
finally:
    cache.close()
```

and here's the output:

```
['targets.xml']
['accounts_with_transactions.xml', 'targets.xml']
['targets.xml', 'accounts_with_transactions.xml']
```

Has anyone run into this before, and is there a workaround without knowing all possible cache keys *a priori*?

Comment: What dbm module are you using? Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: whichdb.whichdb('my.cache') => dbm

Comment: (btw, this is python 2.5 on a mac)

Comment: Can you show the code for your put method?  That isn't part of the standard shelve class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [python library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/shelve.html#restrictions):

> ...The database is also (unfortunately) subject to the limitations of dbm, if it is used — this means that (the pickled representation of) the objects stored in the database should be fairly small...

This correctly reproduces the 'bug':

```
import shelve

a = 'trxns.xml'
b = 'foobar.xml'
c = 'profile.xml'

urls = [a, b, c]
cache = shelve.open('my.cache', 'c')

try:
    cache[a] = a*1000
    cache[b] = b*10000
finally:
    cache.close()


cache = shelve.open('my.cache', 'c')

try:
    print cache.keys()
    print [url for url in urls if cache.has_key(url)]
    print cache.keys()
finally:
    cache.close()
```

with the output:

```
[]
['trxns.xml', 'foobar.xml']
['foobar.xml', 'trxns.xml']
```

The answer, therefore, is don't store anything big—like raw xml—but rather results of calculations in a shelf.

Comment: In Python 2.6 I can't reproduce this "bug".

Comment: You may not be using dbm, try whichdb.whichdb('my.cache'). On my mac, it produces 'dbm'. I haven't tried it out on any other systems yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your examples, my first thought is that `cache.has_key()` has side effects, i.e. this call will add keys to the cache. What do you get for

```
print cache.has_key('xxx')
print list(cache.keys())
```

Comment: I updated the question code with an abbreviated version of urls

Comment: Still doesn't compute; you add a single URL to the cache but after `has_key`, the cache has two URLs. There must be some side effect.

Comment: The cache actually does have 2 urls in there. but keys() doesn't show them both until I test for each explicitly.

Comment: Can you post has_key(), please?